# How to prevent a thread from being killed (and possible alternatives)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread for my android game. It has to run every 15 seconds to update some in-game values and to start 2 other short-living threads.
The problem is as soon as the app is wiped out manually by the user in the task overview the thread also stops to work. The same happens when the OS itself is killing background processes due to low RAM or low battery.

Is there a way to avoid that this thread is killed? If this isn't possible what are my alternatives?

My Thread Class:

```
public class Time extends Thread {
    public static short wait_time = 15_000; //Def val
    public static int time;

    void increase_time() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread running!");
            time++;
            Share_Prices share_prices = new Share_Prices();
            share_prices.start();

            Business_Development business_development = new Business_Development();
            business_development.start();

            Balance.money += My_RealEstate.revenue_of_RE_per_minute();
            share_prices.join();
            business_development.join();

            Worker_Utils.start_Status_Notification_Worker();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crash_Utils.send_to_firebase(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            sleep(2000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Crash_Utils.send_to_firebase(e);
        }
        Share_Prices.create_market_mood();
        while (time < 720) {
            increase_time();
            try {
                sleep(wait_time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Crash_Utils.send_to_firebase(e);
            }
        }
        try {
            Balance.money += Buy_Stocks.daily_dividend();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crash_Utils.send_to_firebase(e);
        }
        Save_Utils.set_values_day_over();

    }
```

Comment: This is working by design; imagine if all apps decided to throw a random thread out there to do things... your phone would run out of battery and you wouldn't even know why. What you can do is either use a ForegroundService (if you need background activity when your app is not foreground) or use WorkerManager to schedule periodic work when conditions are met. Anything other that this (or similar) is going against the Google Framework and I do not recommend it.

Comment: You should re-design your architecture so it doesn't depend on so many external factors (like, for example, the operating system killing random threads when your application process is killed by the user or the OS). I mean, this is a Linux operating system doing what is supposed to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use WorkManager because the Task has to be repeated every 15 secs but WorkManager can only reschedule a task each 15 min.

Comment: But I will take a closer look on ForegroundService

Comment: Here's my take: A Service set as foreground, requires the user to see a permanent notification (until the service is no longer foreground). You said: "as soon as the app is wiped out manually by the user in the task overview the thread also stops to work." Threads are bound to the process that owns them (your App's process). If your process dies, so does the rest. If the game is NOT running, why would you need to run computation values every 15 seconds?

Comment: Store the last state (values), store the timestamp, when the app restarts, reload those, and compute all the values since then (for example) in one pass. (assuming this is what you need, not to lose intermediate values). I don't know your game, nor your architecture, but this is normal application behavior, not game related.

Comment: For what is worth, if the user kills your app (via Settings -> Force Stop), your service will also die. That's why you shouldn't rely on that. What you can do, is use the WorkManager to, every 15 minutes, check how much time has elapsed since the last known calculation was made, perform the calculations as soon as possible, save the new state, and reschedule another check in 15 minutes. The app (on start) would retrieve the last known values and take it from there.

Comment: "...use the WorkManager to, every 15 minutes, check how much time has elapsed since the last known calculation was made". Wait, that's a great idea. I could calculate all the values for the time the app was closed. I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: I think 15 minutes is too short (depending how much data you truly need to process), keep in mind that there's a lot of 15 minute intervals in one full day, that's a lot of CPU and battery. I'd calculate these things once a day if the app is not running, and would reset the timer when the app is launched to do the calculations 24 hours from now. Remember the most expensive operation of your work, is probably turning the CPU on every 15 minutes. It's likely more efficient to turn it on once and work longer than short bursts of 1 sec of computation that involved turning the CPU on. Good luck!.